# Web View not showing the content in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

```
const WebViewExample = () =>(
  <View style = {{height : 350, width : '100%'}}>
       <WebView
         source = {{uri : 'https://www.google.com'}}
         injectJavaScript = {console.log('Injected')}
         scalesPageToFit = {true}
         style = {{backgroundColor : 'gray', marginTop : 20}}
         renderError = {(err)=> console.log(err)}
         startInLoadingState = {true}
         javaScriptEnabled = {true}
         domStorageEnabled = {true}
      /> 
   </View> 
)
```

I have this component rendered inside my App container. But webview not showing the content.

Comment: It shows correctly to me with react-native 0.49.

Comment: even I'm using 4.9. I think it might be problem with the simulator